# Using PHP for data into an xml file

Tags: php, xml

i am trying to use PHP to give data into an xml file , i am trying to do this simple :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Data>
<Entry>  <?php echo("Hello world");?> </Entry>
</Data>
```

but , when i am saving this as a .php file it just shows the "Hello world" message , when i am saving it as a .xml file it takes the php script as string and it shows it as it is .... 
Do you have any idea how it could work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save it as a PHP script. The XML is being output, but you're just not seeing it (probably) because your default `Content-Type` is `text/html`. You can override it, though, using `header`:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
?><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Data>
<Entry>  <?php echo("Hello world");?> </Entry>
</Data>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
header('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>';
echo '<Data><Entry>Hello world</Entry></Data>';
```

Comment: i am not sure what you are doing ... php script in to a php script ? :S

Comment: "php script in to a php script ?"... i don`t understand , what your said